# Can't start Windows Virtual PC while Windows Phone 7 emulator is running

Tags: windows-phone-7, virtualization, virtual-machine

I just tried to test interaction of WP7 application and application working on Ubuntu server. But I can't start virtual mashine due to the error "can't start Virtual PC because another program used virtualization is running". What shall I do to start both WP7 emulator and Virtual PC

Comment: You may be better served @ serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your vm runner only allows one instance of itself to run - so then you should try a different vm runner

Comment: I also tried VirtualBox and VMWare. The same error. obviously they use similar technology of virtualization

Comment: Is this a processor limitation?  (IOW, not enough cores to allow mulitple virtual machine?)

Comment: processor is core i3 (2 real, 2 virtual cores)

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is a hardware accelerated virtual machine and cannot run inside another virtual machine.

Note the system requirements at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570

Comment: I need not run emulator inside VM. I am running them together on windows 7 host

Comment: Sooty, I was confused because you said you were running on a Ubuntu Server